# Add class to table row when glyphicon is clicked and remove when clicked again

Tags: javascript, jquery, glyphicons

I am able to add a class on a glyphicon click but not remove it. Here is my [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/R3nierjvr/poz9dwhg/)

Following is my jQuery. I thought of adding an if statement `if hasClass then remove else addClass "success"`

```
 jQuery(function($){
    $("tbody").on("click",".questCompletion > .glyphicon-ok", function(){
            $(this).parents("tr").addClass("success");
    });

});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [**toggleClass**](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/)

```
 jQuery(function($){
    $("tbody").on("click",".questCompletion > .glyphicon-ok", function(){
            $(this).parents("tr").toggleClass("success");
    });

});
```